# Random forest with a mix of categorical and lexical features

Tags: random-forest, natural-language

I'm working on a binary classification problem for which the dataset is mostly composed of categorical features, but also a few lexical ones (i.e. article titles and abstracts). I'm experimenting with Random Forests, and my current strategy is to build the training set by appending the $k$ best lexical features (chosen with univariate feature selection, and weighted with $tf-idf$) to the full set of categorical features. This works reasonably well, but as I cannot find explicit references to such a strategy of using hybrid features for RF, I have doubts about my approach: does it make sense? Am I "diluting" the power of the RF by doing so, and should I rather try to combine two classifiers specializing on both types of features?

Comment: What is the definition of a lexical feature?

Comment: It's a feature indicating the presence, absence or "weight" of a word in a document (i.e. a "bag of words" model).

Comment: Why dont you just introduce these variables? Random Forest has no restriction on the types of variables you can use. And it is capable of finding quite complex interactions between the variables on the fly so I would first try introducing them in their original form, even all of them as it is equipped with natural feature selection and can handle high dimensional data rather well.